# Iron-router and Meteor : Template rendering on different url

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I have 3 templates. signup, login and public template.

is there  a way that handlebars can perform such logic that it will get the url and render the template?

like:

```
{{#if currentPage 'public'}}
  render public template
{{elseif currentPage 'login'}}
  render login template
{{else}}
  render signup template
{{/if}}
```

Comment: These pages should have separate routes, and each route should specify the template you want to use for that page.

Comment: They have separated routes but their in one page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a helper that does this in the package, but it's easy enough to register one:

```
UI.registerHelper("currentPage", function(localPath) {
    return Router.current(true).path === localPath;
});
```

You could also register this as a helper for a given template, but the above will allow it to be accessed globally.

Note that you'd need to supply parameters with a leading `/` for this to work, like `/public`, `/login`, and so on.